# How to show download button in CM Download Manager plugin without login in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How to show download button in (CM Download Manager plugin)[enter link description here](http://glamourhub.in/cmdownloads/document-of-glamour-hub/) without login in wordpress

You can see here my problem

Answer (score 0):

use can add the group for anonymous user.  Please refer this screen shot for how to do it: https://downloadsmanager.cminds.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/downloadsA1-43184_x410.png 
https://downloadsmanager.cminds.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/downloadsA2-43184_x410.png

Comment: I am not able to view user group,downloads setting option. So plz help me